# Firebase realtime DB, what is difference in these two query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two firebase realtime db queries.

```
Query 1 : firebase.database().ref("Messages/" + suid).child(ids + "/chat").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);

Query 2 :  firebase.database().ref(`Messages/${suid}/${ids}/chat`).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
```

Both queries are working fine, what is difference between query 1 and query 2. Is Query 2 technically correct/reliable or efficient from Query 1. Will it save my download bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, in any case you have a DatabaseReference instance.

A Firebase reference represents a particular location in your Database and can be used for reading or writing data to that Database location.